# How to configure a large number of ports with netsh

Tags: visual-studio, https, ssl-certificate, iis-express, netsh

I have a large number of ports configured with netsh:

```
> netsh http show sslcert
```

shows all ports from `43300` to `43399` are configured with the same certificate. I do not remember doing this myself.

I want to install a new certificate (which I have installed in `mmc.exe`, and which I have installed to one port successfully), but cannot find a way to install all the other ports easily (other than 100 `netsh` commands maybe in a loop?).

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express. I can't see anywhere to import a certificate in Visual Studio. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "I do not remember doing this myself." That's done by IIS Express installer. "but cannot find a way to install all the other ports easily (other than 100 netsh commands maybe in a loop?)" Why cannot you use such a loop?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I guessed it was done automatically somehow. Yes, I can do a loop myself. Or just update the ports I am using.